# Negative Margins not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

I hate to be that person who asks the stupid questions, but I've been searching all morning and can't seem to work this one out.

I'm implementing a rather dirty hack to make an advertising wrap clickable on a website.

The boxes are currently highlighted in red and yellow, and work as expected in chrome and firefox.

Naturally IE falls apart, and I've no idea why.

The html and css is actually very simple.

CSS:

```
#box-link2 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 173px; 
    width: 210px; 
    height: 918px;
    margin-left: -700px;
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:
     `<a id="box-link2" href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_new"></a>`

it positions perfectly in chrome but not IE.

There are 2 other boxes you can see on the dev url: http://cb5tr [dot] tyrereviews [dot] co [dot] uk.

Any help gratefully appreciated, and I'm sorry again for the idiotic question

Comment: Maybe use `left` instead of `margin-left` ? Your link doesn't work nor do you have any html code to give you an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `margin-left` for absolutely positioned element when you can use `left`?

```
#box-link2 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 173px; 
    width: 210px; 
    height: 918px;
    left: -700px;
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What is more I believe you have to have an element to which you can position your block relatively to get margin working.

Comment: using left instead of margin left does nothing for the situation in IE, and breaks it in chrome / firefox :)

Comment: What do you mean by saying "breaks"? Can you provide jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: I didn't know about jfiddle, nice site! https://jsfiddle.net/2a9sd0p2/ <- is the current version working in chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.

I just needed to declare "left:50%;" and IE is now happy.

Idiot question, idiot solution :(